# A not constant unit in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and another one in $\mathbb{Z}/96\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

Could someone help me to find a unit (not constant) in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z}[X]$ ?
And another one in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/96\mathbb{Z}[X]$ ?

---

I have done the following:

Let we take a polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z}[X]$. $f$ will be a unit if there exists another polynomial $g\in\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $f\cdot{g} =1$.

I also know that the polynomials from $\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z}[X]$ have their coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z}=\{\bar0,\bar1,\bar2,...,\bar{26}\}$ and $\bar{a}=\bar{b}\leftrightarrow a\equiv b\pmod {27} $

But how can I follow now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $R$ be a ring and $a \in R$ be nonzero nilpotent, i.e., let $a \neq 0$ be such that $a^n = 0$ for $n \geqslant 1$.
Consider the polynomial $f(X) = 1 - aX \in R[X]$. What happens if you multiply with $1 + aX$? What if you multiply that with $1 + a^2X^2$? Then with $1 + a^4X^4$?...

---

A more general result:

> A polynomial in $R[x]$ is a unit iff the constant coefficient is a unit in $R$ and the other coefficients are nilpotent.

Comment: I don't know if I have understood well.. In $\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z}[X]$ if I take $\bar2$ as the constant (because it is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z}$ ) and $\bar3$ as the coefficient of $X$ (because it is nilpotent; $\bar3 ^3=0$), I mean, if I take $f(X)=\bar2 + \bar3 X$, is $f$ a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z}[X]$ ???

Comment: @User160: Yes. You can multiply $f(X)$ with a unit and it won't change its invertibility. So, multiplying with $\overline{14} = \overline{2}^{-1}$ gives you $g(X) = \bar{1} - \bar{3} X$. Now you can follow the procedure in given to see that $g(X)$ has an inverse, namely $(1 + \bar{3}X)(1 + \bar{9}X^2) = 1 + \overline{3}X + \bar{9}X^2$.

Comment: @User160: To be explicit, multiplying that last polynomial with $\overline{14}$ will give you the inverse of your $f(X)$. So we have $$(\bar{2} + \bar{3}X)^{-1} = \overline{14} + \overline{15}X + \overline{18}X^2.$$

Comment: which last polynomial??

Comment: @User160: The one in my comment before that: $1 + \overline{3}X + \bar{9}X^2$.

Comment: but if you multiply $f(X)$ with $\bar{14} +\bar{15}X +\bar{18} X^2$ is not $\bar{1}$, no?

Comment: @User160: possibly not. In any case, I've laid out the calculations that are to be done. You can do the precise computations yourself. As long as you've understood how to invert things like $1 + 3X$.